# Wordpress arvhive page doesn't based on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, archive, custom-post-type

Ok so I made this wordpress archive-mynews.php and a single-mynews.php
single-mynews.php contains the comment to let wordpress know this is my single page "Template Name: Single Mynews".

Now when I hit http://url.com/mynews it redirects me to the home page instead of to the archive page I just created. Why is this, am I forgetting something?

I already made a custom post type in functions.php
I did it like hits.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'mynews',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Mynews' ),
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'mynews'),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Mynews' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
        )
    );
}
```

Can anybody tell me why it's not working or what I am forgetting because I can't seam to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code are you using in archive-mynews.php?

Comment: I fixed it, It all was just working fine. I only had to re-update the settings for the permalinks under Settings>Permalink I just hit this button and after that everything worked fine. 

Kinda strange I had to update the permalink settings in order to let the changes take effect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by going to "Settings>Permalinks" and just hit the save changes button to let the changes take effect.